# Is there a way to do this in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making an HTML based game. In this game, 5 words are chosen at complete randomness. Everything's fine, the code picks 5 words at random, and displays it on the screen, right?

Well I don't like the way the words end up getting styled, and it pretty much looks like this:

[image]

So the goal is to end up making the text look like this.

[image: pretty bad photoshopped goal]

So far, I haven't tried anything because I didn't really know what to do, however the only one attempted using was inline-block, and it somewhat helped, but not to the full extent of how I want it. Here is the current source code:

```
<body>
  <div class="content" id="content">
    <div class="wordBank" id="wordBank">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
var wordBank = document.getElementById("wordBank")
// sparing you some of the unneeded stuff, this is just the word array
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  wordBank.innerHTML += "<p>" + words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)] + "</p>"
}
```

```
    body {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .content {
      width: 512px;
      height: 512px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    .wordBank {
      border: 2.5px solid black;
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
```

How can I achieve my goal effectively?

Comment: You probably want to learn about `position:absolute` in CSS. That will allow you to put the words wherever you want on the screen. If you want them to appear in random places you can generate random X/Y coordinates - and in css those could be `top:Ypx; left: Xpx` which you would include as an inline `style` on your `p` tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this: https://codepen.io/c_sharp_/pen/ZEvjvqg

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="item">multiply</span>
    <span class="item even">step</span>
    <span class="item">kiss</span>
    <span class="item even">force</span>
    <span class="item">ago</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 500px;
}
.even {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

alternatively,

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 500px;
}
.wrapper > :nth-of-type(even) {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

The numbers are (obviously) placeholders and fit them as you like.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It came out a little flipped how i expected it, but it's fixed now!

Comment: Is there a way that the words can have a little bit of space between the border as well?

Comment: There are a few ways:
1. You could set a padding to the `wrapper` class to make the entire box have some padding inside
2. You could use `space-around` instead of `space-between`.

I'm sure there are more ways.

Comment: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a great guide to how `flex` works, but nowadays, `grid` is replacing `flex` in a lot of use cases, so you might want to take a look at `grid`s as well.

Comment: You don't even need the classes on the spans, `.wrapper > :nth-of-type(even) { align-self: flex-end; }` would do the same.