# Needing help forcing the div to be stuck right under this other div in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this is day 2 of making an HTML game. I am honestly convinced I'm making a lot of progress and I am, except, [yet again,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835496/is-there-a-way-to-do-this-in-css) I run into another styling problem.

So there is a grid in the game that updates every time the game is loaded. Basically, the grid's length and width to the word with the most letters, as shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the word everyday is 8 letters long, so the game puts 8 spaces available.

Now here's two problems with this in general:

- I want the word bank to be directly UNDER the grid, no matter the length of the grids.
- I want the grids to have NO space under them, so you see the little space between every new row? Basically that needs to go poof, and not be there.

**What have you tried so far?**

Placing the word bank div under the game area div didn't work, so I started to look up some solutions on Google, and it told me to try to add position: absolute; and position: relative; to div 1 and 2, but that just created a mess when it came to the word bank (spacing it out WAY too much) and did nothing to the grids. Also, display: block; can't help, because the code is already using flex for a different reason.

I also tried using margin-bottom for the grid space problem, but did nothing.

Code:

```js
// definitely didn't get the grid part from Stack Overflow
var score = 0;
var scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score");
scoreDisplay.innerHTML = "<p>Score: " + score;
var wordBank = document.getElementById("wordBank")
var gameArea = document.getElementById("gameArea")
let rows = document.getElementsByClassName("gridRow");
let cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
// sparing you word array, nobody wants to read that list to the very last bits
var selectedWords = []
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const selectedWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  if (selectedWord.length <= 9) {
    wordBank.innerHTML += "<span>" + selectedWord + "</span>"
    selectedWords.push(selectedWord)
  }
}
var longestWord = selectedWords.reduce((a, b) => a.length < b.length ? b : a, "")
var charCount = longestWord.length

function makeRows(rowNum) {
  for (r = 0; r < rowNum; r++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    gameArea.appendChild(row).className = "gridRow";
  };
};

function makeColumns(cellNum) {
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cellNum; j++) {
      let newCell = document.createElement("div");
      rows[j].appendChild(newCell).className = "cell";
    };

  };
};

function defaultGrid() {
  makeRows(charCount);
  makeColumns(charCount);
}
defaultGrid();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.content {
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.score {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.wordBank {
  border: 2.5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 13%;
}

.wordBank> :nth-of-type(even) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.gameArea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content">
  <div class="gameArea" id="gameArea">
  </div>
  <div class="wordBank" id="wordBank">
  </div>
  <div class="score" id="score">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this issue? Any help is appreciated!

(Example for David):
[image]

Comment: I've converted your three posted code examples into one runnable Stack Snippet, that can be run in the question. Can you verify that this accurately reproduces your problem (currently it probably doesn't, since there's a `ReferenceError: words is not defined`)?

Comment: oh yeah, thats cause i left out the words array (it's PRETTY long)

Comment: Yeah, I gathered that; we don't need *all* the words, just a few; this is to show how your code handles its input, and what the result is. It doesn't need to be the whole app, or site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// replaced all uses of 'var' with either let (if I anticipated the value would change), or const
// (if the value was likely to be unchanging):
let score = 0;
const scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score");
const wordBank = document.getElementById("wordBank")
const gameArea = document.getElementById("gameArea")
const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("gridRow");
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
// created an Array of words (though ideally a minimal, demonstrative Array would have been in the
// posted MCVE demo code); obviously: replace with your own Array:
const words = ['hello', 'thrifty', 'gaol', 'maester', 'mandible', 'osteoarthritic', 'venerable', 'the', 'cursive'];
let selectedWords = []

// moved this line out of the variable assignments/initialisation, in order that it's easier to
// maintain the code, because related things/actions are in the same/similar place(s):
scoreDisplay.innerHTML = "<p>Score: " + score;

// the rest of the JavaScript I left alone, with the exception of adding a 'let' declaration in the
// for loops after this first one:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const selectedWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  if (selectedWord.length <= 9) {
    wordBank.innerHTML += "<span>" + selectedWord + "</span>"
    selectedWords.push(selectedWord)
  }
}
let longestWord = selectedWords.reduce((a, b) => a.length < b.length ? b : a, "")
let charCount = longestWord.length

function makeRows(rowNum) {
  for (let r = 0; r < rowNum; r++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    gameArea.appendChild(row).className = "gridRow";
  }
}

function makeColumns(cellNum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cellNum; j++) {
      let newCell = document.createElement("div");
      rows[j].appendChild(newCell).className = "cell";
    }
  }
}

function defaultGrid() {
  makeRows(charCount);
  makeColumns(charCount);
}
defaultGrid();
```

```css
/* added a simple, minimal CSS reset to normalise all element defaults
   to a similar layout-sizing method, and font-family: */

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* added this, to help lay out the various elements more clearly: */

.content {
  display: grid;
  /* defining three rows, each of which is sized to the maximum size
     needed to clearly display the content within: */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, max-content);
  /* setting a margin around the element on the block-axis, which is
     perpendicular to the inline-axis, the inline-axis being the
     direction of writing in the local language; so in left-to-right
     languages this results in a top, and bottom, margin of 1em: */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* setting a margin of auto on the inline-axis, the left and right
     margins of the element in a left-to-right language: */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* I retained the width, but removed the height constraint: */
  width: 512px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.wordBank {
  border: 2.5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  /* I left this part more ore less alone, other than adjusting
     the font-size to an 'em' based sizing for responsive purposes: */
  font-size: 1.6em;
  /* added a minimum height, in order to allow room for the words
     to move to the end within the space: */
  min-height: 3em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.wordBank span:nth-child(even) {
  align-self: end;
}

.gameArea {
 /* removing the spaces below/between each .gridRow element, which are caused by
    the newline and whitespace characters between the .gridRow elements: */
  font-size: 0;
  /* placing the game area 'board' horizontally centered in the layout */
  justify-self: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  /* resetting the font-size, so that text is visible once more (despite the parent
     having a font-size of 0): */
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content">
  <div class="gameArea" id="gameArea">
  </div>
  <div class="wordBank" id="wordBank">
  </div>
  <div class="score" id="score">
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qLd4gnvc/).

Further to the question in the comments (below):

> [...]one problem, why do only four words appear [in] certain instances?

This is a result of your loop, and its check:

```
// here, i is initialised to 0 (first iteration),
// the assessment is then executed; if it evaluates
// to true the loop runs an iteration, otherwise
// if the assessment returns false the loop stops;
// after the assessment i is incremented:
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // selecting a random word:
  const selectedWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  // testing the length of that random word:
  if (selectedWord.length <= 9) {
    // if the 'if' statement evaluates to true:
    wordBank.innerHTML += "<span>" + selectedWord + "</span>"
    // adding the selectedWord to the selectedWords Array
    selectedWords.push(selectedWord)
  // if the 'if' statement evaluates to false nothing
  // happens, the loop runs another iteration; this
  // 'consumes' a loop but no word was added hence
  // a smaller selectedWords Array
  } 
}
```

To guard against this, you could modify your loop:

```js
let score = 0;
const scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score");
const wordBank = document.getElementById("wordBank")
const gameArea = document.getElementById("gameArea")
const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("gridRow");
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
const words = ['hello', 'thrifty', 'gaol', 'maester', 'mandible', 'osteoarthritic', 'venerable', 'the', 'cursive'];
let selectedWords = [];

scoreDisplay.innerHTML = "<p>Score: " + score;

// using a while() loop, and testing the length of the selectedWords Array, so that
// while the condition is true (and the Array-length is less than 5) the loop will
// continue running:
while (selectedWords.length < 5) {
  // select random word:
  const selectedWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  // test the length of that word is less than 9 characters:
  if (selectedWord.length <= 9) {
    // adding content to the wordBank element:
    wordBank.innerHTML += "<span>" + selectedWord + "</span>"
    // pushing the word to the Array:
    selectedWords.push(selectedWord);
    // if no word is added to the Array, the length of the Array doesn't change
    // and so the while loop will run again.
  }
}
let longestWord = selectedWords.reduce((a, b) => a.length < b.length ? b : a, "")
let charCount = longestWord.length

function makeRows(rowNum) {
  for (let r = 0; r < rowNum; r++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    gameArea.appendChild(row).className = "gridRow";
  }
}

function makeColumns(cellNum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cellNum; j++) {
      let newCell = document.createElement("div");
      rows[j].appendChild(newCell).className = "cell";
    }
  }
}

function defaultGrid() {
  makeRows(charCount);
  makeColumns(charCount);
}
defaultGrid();
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, max-content);
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: 512px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.wordBank {
  border: 2.5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  min-height: 3em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.wordBank span:nth-child(even) {
  align-self: end;
}

.gameArea {
  font-size: 0;
  justify-self: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content">
  <div class="gameArea" id="gameArea">
  </div>
  <div class="wordBank" id="wordBank">
  </div>
  <div class="score" id="score">
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qLd4gnvc/1/).

Note that there is an infinitesimally small chance that this may lead to an infinite loop – though to do so would require that every iteration of the `while` loop selects a random word longer than 9 characters in length – so it may be worth modifying further, to filter the Array and first remove all words with more than 9 characters:

```
// you didn't include your own Array, so I'm not sure how
// it's assigned; but you should be able to use
// Array.prototype.filter():
const words = ['hello', 'thrifty', 'gaol', 'maester', 'mandible', 'osteoarthritic', 'venerable', 'the', 'cursive']
  // here we use an Arrow function to filter the words
  // of the words Array:
  .filter(
    // passing in a reference to the current Array-element
    // ('word') of the Array over which we're iterating;
    // here we're testing that the length of the current
    // word is less than 9; if so this assessment returns
    // Boolean true, and the word is retained in the Array,
    // otherwise it returns false and the word is discarded:
    (word) => word.length < 9
  );

// ...code omitted for brevity...

// again, using a while loop, to ensure that we
// have five Array-elements in the selectedWords
// Array:
while (selectedWords.length < 5) {
  // no 'if' to check the length, as it's now
  // unnecessary to do so:
  const selectedWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    wordBank.innerHTML += "<span>" + selectedWord + "</span>"
    selectedWords.push(selectedWord);
}
```

```js
let score = 0;
const scoreDisplay = document.getElementById("score");
const wordBank = document.getElementById("wordBank")
const gameArea = document.getElementById("gameArea")
const rows = document.getElementsByClassName("gridRow");
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
const words = ['hello', 'thrifty', 'gaol', 'maester', 'mandible', 'osteoarthritic', 'venerable', 'the', 'cursive'];
let selectedWords = [];

scoreDisplay.innerHTML = "<p>Score: " + score;

// using a while() loop, and testing the length of the selectedWords Array, so that
// while the condition is true (and the Array-length is less than 5) the loop will
// continue running:
while (selectedWords.length < 5) {
  // select random word:
  const selectedWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  // test the length of that word is less than 9 characters:
  if (selectedWord.length <= 9) {
    // adding content to the wordBank element:
    wordBank.innerHTML += "<span>" + selectedWord + "</span>"
    // pushing the word to the Array:
    selectedWords.push(selectedWord);
    // if no word is added to the Array, the length of the Array doesn't change
    // and so the while loop will run again.
  }
}
let longestWord = selectedWords.reduce((a, b) => a.length < b.length ? b : a, "")
let charCount = longestWord.length

function makeRows(rowNum) {
  for (let r = 0; r < rowNum; r++) {
    let row = document.createElement("div");
    gameArea.appendChild(row).className = "gridRow";
  }
}

function makeColumns(cellNum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cellNum; j++) {
      let newCell = document.createElement("div");
      rows[j].appendChild(newCell).className = "cell";
    }
  }
}

function defaultGrid() {
  makeRows(charCount);
  makeColumns(charCount);
}
defaultGrid();
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, max-content);
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: 512px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: right;
}

.wordBank {
  border: 2.5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  min-height: 3em;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.wordBank span:nth-child(even) {
  align-self: end;
}

.gameArea {
  font-size: 0;
  justify-self: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content">
  <div class="gameArea" id="gameArea">
  </div>
  <div class="wordBank" id="wordBank">
  </div>
  <div class="score" id="score">
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qLd4gnvc/2/).

Comment: Thanks, one problem, why do only four words appear at certain instances?

Comment: I've edited the post to show what happens sometimes

Comment: @1BL1ZZARD: I've address that in an edit to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like this:

So, what I did was to place the `.game-grid`(the n by n grid) and `.words-wrapper` (the zig zag word cloud) in a `.container`. This `.container` is a `flex` that flows in a column. This shows the 2 items inside the `.container` one by one from top to bottom.

`.game-grid` itself is a `grid`. This lets you easily create a grid.
`grid-template-colums: repeat(8, 1fr)` tells the browser that this grid is going to have 8 columns (this you will have to control by the length of the longest word). I set the grid to have a fixed size and all the items inside have `place-items: stretch` which means they take all the available space, so they will all be equal size.

Hope this helps.

```css
.container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .game-grid {
                width: 50vh;
                height: 50vh;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
                place-items: stretch;
                place-content: stretch;
            }

            .game-grid-item {
                border-width: 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: chocolate;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                display: grid;
                place-items: center;
            }
            .words-wrapper {
                display: flex;
                width: 100%;
                justify-content: space-between;
                height: 10vh;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: blueviolet;
            }
            .even {
                align-self: flex-end;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="game-grid">
                <div class="game-grid-item">1</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">2</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">3</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">4</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">5</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">6</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">7</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">8</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">9</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">10</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">11</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">12</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">13</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">14</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">15</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">16</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">1</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">2</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">3</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">4</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">5</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">6</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">7</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">8</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">9</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">10</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">11</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">12</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">13</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">14</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">15</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">16</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">1</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">2</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">3</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">4</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">5</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">6</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">7</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">8</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">9</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">10</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">11</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">12</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">13</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">14</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">15</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">16</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">1</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">2</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">3</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">4</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">5</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">6</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">7</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">8</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">9</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">10</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">11</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">12</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">13</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">14</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">15</div>
                <div class="game-grid-item">16</div>
            </div>
            <div class="words-wrapper">
                <span class="item">multiply</span>
                <span class="item even">step</span>
                <span class="item">kiss</span>
                <span class="item even">force</span>
                <span class="item">ago</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer wasn't the answer, however, I'm still upvoting just for helping me.